# Run event handlers in another thread (without threads blocking)

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, synchronize

I have a class `Communicator` that works in a background thread receiving data on a TCP port.

The Communicator has an event `OnDataReceived` which is of a  `EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs>` type.

There is another class `Consumer` that contains a method subscribed to the `Communicator.OnDataReceived` event.

```
comm.OnDataReceived += consumer.PresentData;
```

The `Consumer` class is created within a Form constructor and then one of its methods is called on another thread. This method is an infinite loop, so it stays in that method during the application execution.

What I'd like to do is for the `Communicator.OnDataReceived` event to invoke the `consumer.PresentData` method on consumer's thread.

Is that even nearly possible? And if it is, what kind of mechanisms (sync classes) should I use?

Comment: Sorry, but not really clear, when you say Consumer runs on other thread. Has it functions that runs infinit thread or object is created within other thread, or something else again?

Comment: @Tigran I have updated the question to answer your comment.

Comment: Which thread is the "consumer's thread" here? The GUI thread or the other one?

Comment: @Henk There are three threads. One is the GUI (starting) thread, the other one is TCP thread, and the third one is the consumer's thread.

Comment: OK, and which is the one you want the events on?

Comment: Communicator raises the events, which I want to consume (via event handler) on the consumer's (third) thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this somewhere in your code: (I usually put this in a static helper class called ISynchronizedInvoke so I can call ISynchronizedInvoke.Invoke(...));

```
public static void Invoke(ISynchronizeInvoke sync, Action action) {
    if (!sync.InvokeRequired) {
        action();
    }
    else {
        object[] args = new object[] { };
        sync.Invoke(action, args);
    }
}
```

Then inside OnDataReceived, you could do:

```
Invoke(consumer, () => consumer.PresentData());
```

This invokes 'consumer.PresentData' on 'consumer'.

As for your design issue (consumer references communicator), you could introduce a method inside communicator such as:

```
class Communicator {
    private ISynchronizeInvoke sync;
    private Action syncAction;

    public void SetSync(ISynchronizeInvoke sync, Action action) {
        this.sync = sync;
        this.syncAction = action;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataReceived(...) {
        if (!sync.InvokeRequired) {
            syncAction();
        }
        else {
            object[] args = new object[] { };
            sync.Invoke(action, args);
        }
    }
}
```

This would give you a way to pass in the ISynchronizedInvoke from your consumer class. So you would be creating the ISynchronizedInvoke in the consumer assembly.

```
class Consumer {
    public void Foo() {
        communicator.SetSync(this, () => this.PresentData());
    }
}
```

So basically you are creating everything  you need to do the invoke, and just passing it in to your communicator. This resolves your necessity to have an instance or reference to consumer in communicator.

Also note that I did not test any of this I am doing this all in theory, but it should work nicely.

Comment: The thing is, the Communicator is in a separate assembly and has no reference to the consumer's class. It's the other way around. If I understand your answer, my customer's class would have to implement ISynchronizeInvoke. Never used it before. Let alone tried to implement it. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @danderson Yes, I am aware of that. I am unable to merge the assemblies, so the only thing to do is to implement ISynchronizeInvoke and to pass the consumer's instance as ISynchronizeInvoke object. But I wonder if I haven't made some design flaws.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. You may create a queue for execution, or look at the Dispatcher object, it's useful (and sometimes mandatory as the only way) to push some methods into the UI Thread, it that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a method to execute on a thread only if the target thread is designed to accept a marshaling operation that transfers the execution of the method from the initiating thread to the target thread.

One way to get this to work is to have your `Consumer` class implement `ISynchronizeInvoke`. Then have your `Communicator` class accept an `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance that it can use to perform the marshaling operation. Take a look at the `System.Timers.Timer` class as an example. `System.Timers.Timer` has the `SynchronizingObject` property that it can use to marshal the `Elapsed` event onto the thread hosting the synchronizing object by calling `ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke` or `ISynchronizeInvoke.BeginInvoke`.

The tricky part is how you implement `ISynchronizeInvoke` on the `Consumer` class. The worker thread started by that class will have to implement the producer-consumer pattern to be able to process delegates. The `BlockingCollection` class would make this relatively easy, but there is still quite a learning curve. Give it a shot and post back with a more focused question if you need more help.